# count is not working after filtering the collection

Tags: collection, magento2.2, filter

I am getting the correct count using code.

```
$this->getCatalogRuleCollection()->count()
```

But when I am adding the filter to it is not working.
Following code is not working.

```
$this->getCatalogRuleCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$entityId)->count()
```

Tried `getSize()` as well, but facing same issue.
Why is this so?
What is the reason for this?
What is the alternative(best method) to getting the count?

Comment: Hi, had you some time to test it?

Comment: @sv3n I will check and post the solution.

Comment: @sv3n I have checked all the solutions posted here, but no one is working. I think addFieldToFilter loads the collection and that's why count or getSize are not working. But I am not sure. Kindly post it here if you got anything for it.

Comment: Hey @AnshuMishra Did you found any solution related this question?

Comment: @RohanHapani No, I didn't get any solution for this. If I remember correctly I have changed the code somewhere else to fulfill the requirement.

Comment: okay. Please add solution here if you found anything. I face same issue right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$this->getCatalogRuleCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$entityId)->getSize();
```

Comment: Tried, but facing the same issue.

Comment: Can you please share your whole so that i can understand more.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $counts = $this->getCatalogRuleCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$entityId);                                              
 print_r(count($counts));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: **[\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionProcessor.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/CatalogRule/Model/ResourceModel/Product/CollectionProcessor.php#L90)** & there is a collection flag being set similarly however you may need to set or `reset()` the data so the `getSize()` will pull in non persistent and/or cached data.

```
$productCollection = $this->getCatalogRuleCollection();
$productCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',$entityId);
$productCollection->setFlag('catalog_rule_loaded', false); // NOTE flag set
$productCollection->getSize();
```

or

`$productCollection->setFlag('catalog_rules_dirty', true);`

```
/**
 * Flag indicates that some rules have changed but changes have not been applied yet.
 */
class Flag extends \Magento\Framework\Flag
{
    /**
     * Flag code
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_flagCode = 'catalog_rules_dirty';
```

Since it seems a lot of Magento 1 code still exists, may help shed more light: [Reload collection after count()](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/reload-collection-after-count?rq=1)

Comment: How will I  know which flag I have to use, I have tried with both the mentioned flag but it is working.