# How to get new/refresh Collection?

Tags: magento2, collection, best-seller

I'm trying to get bestsellers collection, and set a period.
I want to load diffrent period collection if chosen one is empty, but I get old collection instead.
I tried to use clear/reset/load but it doesnt work.

```
$bestsellers = $this->bestsellersCollection->setPeriod($period);

    foreach ($bestsellers as $product) {
        $productIds[] = $product->getProductId();
    }

    if (empty($productIds) && ($period != 'year')){
        $bestsellers->setPeriod('year');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/213009/108929

Try resetting the where condition, And then add the conditions back

Comment: Thanks, that also works. As a workaround I used Bestsellers\CollectionFactory instead of Collection and create new collection in "if" statement.